# Add margin top to all figures

Tags: floats, margins

How can I add a margin (white space) on top of ALL figures? Say, 1 cm or so. Note that I don't want to separate the figure from the page margin, I want to add a top margin to the figures. As example, in HTML and CSS I would do something like this:

```
figure {
    margin-top: 1cm;
}
```

I want to achieve the same result in LaTeX.

Comment: Perhaps: [Figures three spaces after and before text](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/632116)

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn , that is pretty much what I was looking for.